# Query to get distinct ID and random field of it's related field

Tags: mysql

OK, Here is what my table looks like

```
------------------------------------------------
Textid                  type
-----------------------------------------------
1                      a
2                      b
1                      a
1                      c
2                      c
1                      a
3                      a
------------------------------------------------
```

Now, I need a query that can give me this output...

```
-------------------------------------
Distinct(textid)   |   rand(type)   | 
--------------------------------------
1                          a
2                          c
3                          a                   
--------------------------------------
```

rand(type) gives me number.... Do I need to pass a different records inside rand() like `random(SELECT type FROM mytable)`

### UPDATE

I am trying to get a distinct id from the table and random field(type) associated with that distinct id

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You need to give more information about what you're trying to do here as it is not obvious what your logic is.  Why is `2` associated with `c` instead of `b`, for example?  When a type appears twice for a given text id, should it be weighted more strongly or not?

Comment: do you mean you need the *last* type that appears for each Textid?

Comment: Do you simply mean a random row? (Sounds like the same thing.)

Comment: I mean a random row field with textid='1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  textid,
        (
        SELECT  type
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.textid = md.textid
        ORDER BY
                RAND()
        LIMIT 1
        )
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT textid
        FROM    mytable 
        ) md
```

Create a composite index on `mytable (textid, type)` for this to work fast:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_mytable_textid_type ON mytable (textid, type)
```

Comment: +1, Thank you so much I was really stuck in this point. By the way what do you mean by composite index.. can you brief me a little

Comment: ... when i tried to get two random field... i got an error like `SELECT type, anotherField` gives error

Comment: @mrNepal: please create another question and post your query there.